# How to remove elevation (drop shadow) from a DrawerLayout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, shadow, drawerlayout

How can I remove the elevation (drop shadow) from a `DrawerLayout` in Android Studio? I've looked everywhere, and tried adding `app:elevation="0dp"` and `android:elevation="0dp"` to my `DrawerLayout` xml, but it doesn't work.

I even tried adding `setElevation(0f)` to my `MainActivity`, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

(P.S. The project's base API is 16... I tried changing it to 21, but that didn't make any difference.)

Here's my onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "MUHAHA BURP BARF BARF WHAHAHA", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        populateListView();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. Turns out I was trying to remove the elevation from `drawer_layout` when I should've been removing it from `drawer`. Putting `drawer.setDrawerElevation(0f);` in my `MainActivity` fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?
The drawer is made of two parts, DrawerLayout and NavigationView, and this doesn't seem to work for me when using DrawerLayout.
And NavigationView requires higher API to set elevation programatically.